# NgRx does not trigger selector after state change

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular-standalone-components

I am setting up NgRx in an Angular 16 project using Standalone components. I'm going crazy trying to have a piece of state automatically update the component after an API call is made.

I have defined actions:

```
export const SchoolApiActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Schools API',
  events: {
    getSchoolPreviews: emptyProps(),
    getSchoolPreviewsSuccess: props<{ schoolPreviews: SchoolPreview[] }>(),
    getSchoolPreviewsFail: props<{ error: any }>(),
  },
});
```

I have an effect set up that will trigger when the `getSchoolPreviews` action is dispatched:

```
  loadSchoolPreviews$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviews),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.schoolsService.getSchoolPreviews().pipe(
          map((schoolPreviews) =>
            SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviewsSuccess({
              schoolPreviews,
            })
          ),
          catchError((error) =>
            of(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviewsFail({ error }))
          )
        );
      })
    );
  });
```

Finally, I have a reducer and a selector to modify the state and provide a slice of state:

```
export interface SchoolsState {
  schoolPreviews: SchoolPreview[];
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
}

export const initialState: SchoolsState = {
  schoolPreviews: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};


export const schoolsReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  // School Previews
  on(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviews, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  })),
  on(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviewsSuccess, (state, payload) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      schoolPreviews: [...payload.schoolPreviews],
      loading: false,
    };
  }),
  on(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviewsFail, (state, { error }) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    error,
  })),
);

export const getSchoolPreviews = (state: SchoolsState) => state.schoolPreviews;
```

In the component, I then have the following setup in my `onInit`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.schoolPreviews$ = this.store.select(getSchoolPreviews);
    this.store.dispatch(SchoolApiActions.getSchoolPreviews());
  }
```

And in my template, I am using an async pipe operator to subscribe to the state:

```
<div class="col-4 mt-4">
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="School select" (change)="selectSchool($event)">
    <option selected [value]="-1">Select a School</option>
    <option *ngFor="let schoolPreview of schoolPreviews$ | async" [value]="schoolPreview.id">
      {{ schoolPreview.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have validated that the action/effect is getting triggered, the API call is successful, and the state is updated via the Redux dev tools.

But no matter what I do, I cannot get the async pipe to show the updated state. It fires once, then never again. I've tried changing the change detection strategy, changing how I am setting up the new array in the state, and nothing has made any difference.

Am I missing something simple? Why is the state change not reflected?

Comment: Can you please add a working version of this to Stackblitz or an equivalent online IDE.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the code more carefully, I realized I was missing a feature selector. Modifying my selectors as seen below fixed it.

```
export const SCHOOLS_FEATURE_KEY = 'schools';
export const schoolsFeatureState =
  createFeatureSelector<SchoolsState>(SCHOOLS_FEATURE_KEY);

export const getSchoolPreviews = createSelector(
  schoolsFeatureState,
  (state) => state.schoolPreviews
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to subscribe the selectors in the if you will not subscribe the selector it will not trigger.

`this.store.pipe(select(getSchoolPreviews)).subscribe((res)=>{ this.schoolPreviews$ = res; });`

Comment: He's using the `async` pipe, so it will be subscribed to.